# How the comparisons "if (arr<=arr1)" works in the given program?

Tags: c, pointers, comparison

How this comparison works?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char arr[]="WELCOME";
    char arr1[]="WELCOME";

    if (arr<=arr1)
      printf("equal");
    else
      printf("not equal");

    return 0;
}
```

In this program that if condition this always go to else,
so please some one help me how that comparison done here.

Answer (score 2):

The comparison ends up asking where the two arrays `arr` and `arr1` are located with respect to each other in memory.  It is asking which one has the lower address.

If you're trying to compare the string values contained in the two arrays, use strcmp:

```
if(strcmp(arr, arr1) <= 0) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge goes, `arr` or as a matter of fact any array variable stores the address of the first element in the array. So when you do `arr<=arr1` you are actually comparing their addresses. So that's what it does.

P.S. you can print the addresses just in case you want to check. As in:
`printf("\n%p", (void*) arr);`

From the looks of your program, it seems that you want to compare the two strings. You then have to do:

```
if(strcmp(arr,arr1)==0)
  printf("Entered strings are equal.\n");
else
  printf("Entered strings are not equal.\n");
```

Comment: This `printf("\n%d",arr);` provokes UB. To print the address of the array, thus the address of its 1st element use `printf("\n%p", (void*) arr);`